# How do I access all the attributes of view in android studio arctic Fox

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

How do I access all the attributes of view in android studio arctic Fox.
I am trying to access all the constraints of a button in android Studio arctic fox but can't seem to find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all click on the button, then look to your upper right, u should see the "attributes" tab.click on it, then click on "layout" and you should see what you are looking for.